Как обработать ошибку метода as_ptr()?
Как правильно обработать ошибку method not found, например для чисел из примера ниже?
fn main() {

   let n: u8 = 33;
   // if let _v = &n.as_ptr() {println!("{:?}", _v)} else {println!("method not found in `u8`")};

   let val = match  &n.as_ptr() {

      Ok(value) => value,
      Err(error) => println!("method not found in `u8`"),
   };
   
   println!("{:?}", val);
}


Ошибки компиляции нужно не «обрабатывать», а исправлять некорректно написанный код

@andreymal понятно, спасибо.

Собственно, для получения сырого указателя на число никакго специального метода не надо, а достаточно скастовать ссылку let val = &n as *const u8; (но если вам в принципе зачем-то понадобился сырой указатель, то скорее всего вы что-то делаете очень сильно не так, ведь Rust был придуман специально для того, чтобы сырые указатели были не нужны)

@andreymal, да, если правильно понял, то метод для данных, значения которых только в стеке, - не работает, а для иных, возвращает: (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cea56da97aa234d8b5970322050ea5cb)

Необработанный указатель (raw pointer) из примера по вышеуказанной ссылке и сырой указатель возвращают разные адреса. Так должно быть, т.е. у них разное предназначение и исходный контекст?

Во-первых, «необработанный» и «сырой» это одно и то же, во-вторых, использование стека никак не влияет на работоспособность указателей, а в-третьих, &s2 as *const String даёт указатель на структуру String (которая лежит в стеке), а s2.as_ptr() даёт указатель на массив, которым владеет структура String (и этот массив лежит уже в куче) — это совсем разные вещи и соответственно разные указатели

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.
